# What is the best way to incorporate flash file as a url in webapplication?

Tags: java, integration, opendocument, xcelsius

I am planning to integrate BO Xcelsius dashboards(SWF files) using open doc  with web application.
Right now i have only one option as using Iframe to incorporate it.

Is this secure and fast ?

I need to deal with huge amount of data for swf files.
Is there any other approach you can advise?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an iFrame could definitely work. It's safe as long as you control what is included in the iFrame. Another way to include swf object is to load them in a div using Javascript. You could use for example [Jquery tool Flash embedding](http://jquerytools.org/demos/toolbox/flashembed/index.html).